# Heroku push rejected failed: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6. This causes a build fail

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, handlebars.js

I am getting the error:

> Heroku push rejected failed to define node.js node not defined in package.json

My app works locally, this is an Express MongoDB using handlebars. My gitignore has node_modules in it and the strange part is I am using nodemon and not node.

**package.json:**

```
{
"name": "Jukebox",
"version": "1.1.0",
"engines": {
    "node": "11.3.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
},
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www",
"dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
},
"dependencies": {
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"dotenv": "^6.1.0",
"express": "~4.16.0",
"hbs": "~4.0.1",
"http-errors": "~1.6.2",
"method-override": "^3.0.0",
"mongoose": "^5.3.6",
"morgan": "~1.9.0",
"nodemon": "^1.18.4"
},
"description": "Jukebox is an app where users can add their favorite songs for others to discover. There will be a maximum number of 32 songs that can be added. When user selects genre the artists of that genre will populate the grid and a button will appear to add artist.",
"main": "app.js",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/chuckderosier/Jukebox.git"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/chuckderosier/Jukebox/issues"
},
"homepage": "https://github.com/chuckderosier/Jukebox#readme"
```

}

Comment: I added engines (see above). Added /lib to .gitiginore (it had lib-cov already). I changed event-stream to 3.3.4 in package-lock.json, but it says : npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6. This causes a build fail.

Comment: Hi Chuck, you're missing a necessary dependency for your project: event-stream. Do the following in your cmd line to download it: npm i event-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **specify a Node.js version within your package.json** that matches 
the **runtime you’re developing and testing with**.

Do the following:

1. Within your cmd line type: `node --version` and see what version of Node you're developing with.
2. **Add an engines section within your package.json** specifying your node version from step 1. For example something similar to this:

`"engines": {
    "node": "10.3.0"
}`

For more information checkout the Heroku documentation for Nodejs [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)